# How to convert existing iOS native application into iOS titanium module

Tags: ios4, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I have followed http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/iOS+Module+Development+Guide and created a ios module and integrated it to titanium application. Now kindly help me how to convert an existing iOS4 (iPhone) application into iOS module for titanium.

My question might be very sily, kindly help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Titanium mobile uses its native javascript to develop modules. At compile time it translates the source code into native code.
And as per your situation you have a native application in iOS 4, so in order to convert it to titanium you got to create the application from scratch in titanium using its native javascript.
I don't think there is any trick or application that converts a native iOS application to titanium.

Comment: Anyidea about iOS module of Titanium? If i can make this iOS module of titanium to communicate wiht my native application, then it should help me..

Comment: I don't think your iOS module can communicate directly with your titanium module. You need to have some intermediate services like API for that. But wont suggest such a thing because it would be a lot of mess to solve if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Oops, but somehow i need to make my native application with Titatnium app . THis is the requirement unfortunately, kindly suggest

Comment: But tell the problem that you are facing to get started with titanium app ? There is no other way then starting the app in titanium from scratch.

Comment: I have started the Titanium application, i have two tabs in it. First tab contains set of views which already exists as an native application built in Objective C. So now i created an iOS module for titanium as mentioned in the following wiki link. http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/iOS+Module+Development+Guide Now i need to somehow modify my existing native application come inside the created iOS module. Kindly let me know whether u got my requirement clearly. :)

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be by creating an empty module and putting your existing code inside it. The tricky part is getting rid of your own Appdelegate and attching the Modules delegate to your source.

You can show any of your view controllers as follows

```
 [[TiApp app] showModalController:myViewController animated:YES];
```